# Can we publish event/message AWS SNS from ServiceNow instance?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

We are using ServiceNow instance Jakarta version.We are using SNOW incident table REST API for creating incidents from our server now I want all the updates of that incidents from SNOW to our server, is it possible to publish message/event on AWS SNS or any other option to get back our server when incident update (i.e state changed ,priority changed,resolved,closed etc) in SNOW.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question. Yes, it is possible. I suggest you take a look [here.](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/istanbul-it-operations-management/page/product/amazon-web-services/concept/c_ConfiguringAWS.html) ServiceNow doc that walks you through how to add your AWS account.

[This link](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/istanbul-it-operations-management/page/product/amazon-ec2-cloud-provisioning/task/t_AWSConfigIntegration.html) talks a bit more about SNS notifications and ServiceNow together.

I hope this at least helps point you in the right direction. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, provided document is for istanbul version. can you please let me know same possibilities for Jakarta version?